# "I learned that...." Vs. "I came to know that" Vs. "I found out that"

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

More often than not I come across a sentence structure like this:

> Upon arrival, **I learned that** she was not in the town.

But if I change it this way, does it change the meaning?

> Upon arrival, **I came to know that** she was not in the town.

Furthermore, as oerkelens came up with a good point (more common?)

> Upon arrival, **I found out that** she was not in the town.

**The Question:**

Is *learn* preferred if it's ***news?*** Or something which is ***noesis?*** I thought of several examples and could replace *learned* with *came to know* in almost all cases (of course, except *learned a lesson*). Is there any instance wherein ***"I learned that..."*** cannot be replaced by ***"I came to know that..."***

My understanding: As I said, I think *learn* is more common when it's *news* that you did not expect. On the other hand, *I came to know* is less surprising and *subconsciously* known to us as a second option. Furthermore, *I found out...* is something that comes after you *putting some efforts*.

Having said this, *If you learn that she's not in the town,* it's the news and bit surprising whereas *If you come to know that she's not in the town,* it's **okay** without any *surprising element.* You, though subconsciously, knew the *possibility* of the second option of her being not in the town. *If you found out that she's not in the town,* you made some efforts to *learn/know* the news.

**Note:** I'm particular about putting the word *that* in the sentences in question. Or else, *I learned...* and *I came to know...* are two different things, it's clear to me.

Answer (score 4):

There's some nuanced differences between the two. *I came to know* implies a more lengthy, substantial or involved process of acquiring knowledge than *I learned*. Synonyms of *come to know* include *come to understand* and *become acquainted with*, which are a little more distant from *learn*. For example, *I came to know calculus* suggests a drawn out process or a deeper, more personal relationship with the subject than *I learned*.

I don't know of any instances where *I learned* cannot be validly replaced by *I came to know*, but I do know that the exchange doesn't always work in the other direction. *I came to know my neighbor* is fine, but *I learned my neighbor* is unsemantic (people are not facts or ideas; you cannot *learn* them). I discount *learned a lesson* here because it carries a very specific meaning and uses *learn* in a different sense than usual. [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/learn-a-lesson) even lists it as a phrasal verb (or at least thinks it merits a separate entry).

However, your question includes *that* after both phrases. Having *that* makes it about *some particular pieces of information*. In this case, *came to know* is a superset of *learned*, because both are completed processes of acquiring knowledge, and *learning* is about retaining specific facts. Because of this, I can't think of any cases where one works and the other doesn't if you include *that*.

Regarding your example, what's the context? Was the discovery of this information expedient and easy? Is the sentence intended to be merely informational? If so, use *learned*. Was it very difficult or time consuming to find out the woman's status? Is it the knowledge extremely important and worth emphasizing? Are you trying to avoid being prosaic? If so, use *came to know*. Compare:

> I flew to Bangladesh to see my cousin. After landing, I went to a restaurant to meet her and her husband. Upon arrival, *I learned that* she was not in town. She had to make a business trip and would return the following week.
>
> Tracking the billionaire's wife across Europe was no easy task, but I finally found out she was in Madrid, so I double timed it over there. Upon arrival, *I came to know that* she was not in town. I asked around at the likely clubs and bribed clerks at the upscale hotels, but if anyone had seen her they weren't talking.

Comment: Yes, I am *very specific* about putting ***that*** in those sentences. The question, without *that* is quite clear to me. Looking at your answer, I thought (and so edited) that it's important to mention it there.

Comment: *Found out* is by a wide margin the one that expresses the most surprise. If I had to pick, I'd say *came to know* would be more likely to describe unexpected knowledge than *learned*, but neither one inherently has that implication, while *found out* does. It's worth noting that *found out* is informal while the other two aren't. You might also consider *discovered* if you want to convey surprise.

Answer (score 2):

When looking at the semantics of verbs, it's often useful to understand that actions are generally conceptualized as having 3 phases:  1) a beginning, 2) a happening, and 3) an ending. "Walk" is a good example. The beginning of a walk cycle is "take a step." The happening is the walk cycle itself, a person propelling herself by shifting her weight, moving her legs and feet to maintain balance, etc., and the ending is "come to a stop."

Some verbs, as we can see, are actually meant to communicate one or more phases of other verbs. "To start" and "to finish" are very general verbs used for this very purpose. "To step forward" is the beginning phase of "to walk."

Now, let's take a look at your examples. I added letters to make this simpler:

a) Upon arrival, I learned that she was not in the town.

b) Upon arrival, I came to know that she was not in the town.

c) Upon arrival, I found out that she was not in the town.

The central concept we are talking about here is the verb "to know." "To know" means something has happened in our mind so that some point of data is readily available and accepted as true based on a body of evidence, etc. "To know" has these three phases: 1) study/ponder/investigate 2) realize/find out/discover/come to know/learn, 3) know/understand. "To know" means we have passed through this 3-phase process.

The interesting thing is that the moment of discovery (i.e., phase 2) passes in an instant, but it is the moment when we go from not knowing or being certain to knowing and being certain. In our experience, it is this instant that often stands in our mind as evidence for the "truth" we know. In your Examples, the speaker has been investigating pondering, etc and upon arriving in this town, passed into phase 2.

Example a) uses "learn." "Learning" generally comes from studying or investigating. Some effort has gone into the process.

Example b) uses "come to know." This has a more passive aspect to it. The knowledge settled upon this person, but perhaps without too much effort on his own part.

Example c) uses "found out." This phrase comes between a) and b) in that it isn't as passive as "come to know," but isn't as active as "learn." Some effort may have gone into the "knowing," but there a real sense that the knowledge came without a great deal of effort. Perhaps someone revealed it.

There are nuances here and likely you'll never get a clear answer unless you speak to someone who has spent a great deal of time studying the semantics of these words.